# How to map JSON property names to our own variable names during serialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to serialize my below JSON to a `DataMetrics` class -

```
String json = "[{\"min\": 0,\"max\": 1209,\"avg\": 1.9203402,\"count\": 7344636,\"sumSq\": 71832774,  \"stddev\": 2.4683187, \"median\": 2,\"percentileMap\": {\"95\": 4},\"metricName\": \"TransactionDuration\",\"dimensions\": {\"env\": \"dev\",\"pool\": \"titan\",\"Name\": \"Client::Sync\", \"Type\": \"Client::Sync\"},\"value\": 14104200}]";
```

Generally, for nested objects like `dimensions` you'll declare another POJO for it

```
class DataMetrics {

private String metricName;
private Map<String, Integer> percentileMap;
private String median;
private String stddev;
private String sumSq;
private String count;
private String avg;
private String max;
private String min;

  private Dimensions dimensions;

  private class Dimensions{
    private String env;
    private String pool;
    private String Name;
  }
}
```

And below is the code I have which works fine -

```
public void test() {
    String json = "[{\"min\": 0,\"max\": 1209,\"avg\": 1.9203402,\"count\": 7344636,\"sumSq\": 71832774,  \"stddev\": 2.4683187, \"median\": 2,\"percentileMap\": {\"95\": 4},\"metricName\": \"TransactionDuration\",\"dimensions\": {\"env\": \"dev\",\"pool\": \"titan\",\"Name\": \"Client::Sync\", \"Type\": \"Client::Sync\"},\"value\": 14104200}]";

    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Type type = new TypeToken<List<DataMetrics>>() {}.getType();
    final List<DataMetrics> records = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Here member variable names is matching the JSON property name exactly as it is.

- `stdDev` => `stddev`
- `name` => `Name`
- `percentile` => `percentileMap`

Now Is there any way, I can have my own variable names and map the JSON property name to those names, if possible? I don't want to keep `Name` as a variable name in my Dimensions class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SerializedName` annotation:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

class DataMetrics {

    [..]

    private Dimensions dimensions;

    private class Dimensions{
        private String env;
        private String pool;
        @SerializedName("Name")
        private String nameYouWant;
    }
}
```